# Lecture notes or short textbooks on complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis, reference-request, book-recommendation

I am looking for a good  relatively short textbook or lecture notes on graduate level complex analysis which does not ignore the rest of the mathematics (what I mean is that a lot of texbooks avoid mentioning fundamental group, differential forms, stokes theorem and so on).

I intend not to learn the subject but rather refresh my memory, get my knowledge in order. I want it to contain all the classical results (Cauchy's theorems, Laurent series, maximum module principle,  Shwartz lemma and so on).

Comment: I generally find a book of "Mathematics for Physicists" gives good review summaries, such as Arfken and Weber.

Comment: Is it still ok if I am not a physicist?

Comment: Absolutely. Arfken and Weber is a pure math book, just with a real focus on the math that physicists need.  As such, it does include a lot of cross-connections.  That book is essentially about 16 different textbooks summarized.

Comment: Henri Cartan's textbook on complex analysis seems like it fits the bill: it's relatively short (200ish pages total), and about the first 3 chapters cover all the basics: formal power series, integration of forms, homotopy of curves, closed and exact forms, Green's theorem, Cauchy's theorems, Laurent expansions, max modulus, Schwarz's reflection principle and lemma, Riemann Sphere, residues, and other stuff later on like introduction to complex manifolds and Riemann surfaces.

Answer (score 5):

For someone with at least a tangential interest in the number-theoretic (zeta function! elliptic functions, modular forms) origins of quite a bit of (classical) complex analysis, my own notes are intended to provide a reasonable introduction. [http://www.math.umn.edu/~garrett/m/complex/](http://www.math.umn.edu/%7Egarrett/m/complex/)

The "connection with the rest of mathematics" is a very good criterion to apply! My own notes don't do so much the connection with multi-variable calculus (differential forms and such), but more the number-theoretic and intro-algebraic-geometry aspects.

Answer (score 3):

I like the lecture notes by William Chen a lot, here I'd go for his ["Introduction to complex analysis"](http://www.williamchen-mathematics.info/lnicafolder/lnica.html). Also take a look at Beck et al ["A first course in complex analysis"](http://math.sfsu.edu/beck/papers/complex.pdf).

In any case, a web search will probably give a large collection.

Answer (score 2):

Certainly enjoyed Lang's *Complex Analysis* as a Berkeley undergrad.   It's in the GTM series,  the so-called "yellow peril".  Springer-Verlag I think.

Anyway I don't recall much about additional topics,  though I don't think simple connectedness is avoided.   Most or all of the standard topics are covered.

Incidentally it got me far enough to get a marginal pass on the complex analysis qual at Ucla before beginning graduate studies.